# Multibrowser refresh/reload page

Tags: php, refresh, meta-tags

I was using this code to reload the page, however I'd only tested it on Chrome and when I tried it on Firefox I realized it didn't work. How do I make it work in other browsers?

```
echo 'Reloading. <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0">';
```

Thanks

Comment: When do you want the page to reload?  When the user clicks a link?  Every x seconds?

Comment: Hi, I want it to refresh immediately after the users clicks.

Comment: Why?  It will send the user into an infinite loop of refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pushing out invalid HTML, instead, send the actual header using PHP's [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

```
header("Location: http://where.you/want/to/redirect.to");
```

If the page has already loaded (even partially), then this approach will not work -- in that case, either using JavaScript or the `<meta>` tag will do the trick -- just remember that the `<meta>` tag must be added to the `<head>` portion of your HTML file.

Comment: I need to refresh the page when a user clicks something. Not redirect him. What does it mean that it won't work if the page has loaded?

Comment: header("Location:  this will not work if page has sent output means page has loaded fully or partially . it will give error "header already sent "

Answer (score 1):

`<script type="text/javascript">window.location.reload(true);</script>`

What you are doing is telling the browser to refresh. However, the `<meta>` tag you are using is meant to be in the `<head>` part of the document. That is probably why Firefox isn't properly executing it.

If you instead use the blurb above, which is javascript, you can put that code virtually anywhere in the document and it will cause the page to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's not working because it's not in the `<head>` tag.  Generate a properly formatted HTML document and it should work.  But why in the world would you want to refresh the page after zero seconds?

Comment: I don't get it. Is making it wait some seconds going to make it work in other browsers?

Comment: No, putting it into the `<head>` will make it work.  But why do you want to refresh so quick?

Comment: That only runs as a result of submitting a form, that's why it should refresh immediately.

I'm not sure how to do that. What must I put into the header? That code is let's say very far from the header.

Comment: It will refresh indefinitely.  It will not stop until the user presses the "stop" button in their browser.